# Normalization of a four-velocity when constructing the metric from the EM tensor

Tags: general-relativity, gauge

I've been following the [MIT General Relativity Course](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/8-962-general-relativity-spring-2020/). In lecture (14) the concept of linearized gravity is introduced. This is then demonstrated by showing how we can recieve the Newtonian limit from such a approach.

We assume we have the metric that can be locally written as

$$
g_{\mu \nu} = \eta_{\mu \nu} + h_{\mu \nu}
$$
where $\eta$ is the Minkowski metric and $h$ is a correction, we work only in the order $O(h^2)$.
Using the correct gauge we recieve the equations
$$
\Box \bar{h}_{\alpha\beta} = -16 \pi G \ T_{\alpha\beta}.
$$
where $\bar{h}$ is the trace free part of $h$, i.e. $\bar{h}_{\alpha\beta}= h_{\alpha\beta}- \frac{1}{2}\eta_{\alpha\beta}h$.

Now the lecturer then says, if consider static non-relativistic perfect fluid solution, we have that $$T_{\mu \nu} = \rho u_\mu u_\nu, $$ since this is static the pertubation $h$ must be indepedent of the time parameter, we neglect the preassure part of $T$.

Now presumably if we consider the observer $u_\mu = \{1,0,0,0\}$ we get

$$
T_{00} = \rho
$$

and all other terms zero, we then get the metric

$$
ds^2 = -(1+ 2 \Phi) dt^2 + (1- 2 \Phi) (dx^2 + dy^2 + dz^2),
$$
with $\Phi$ being the Newtonian potential.

But I am really not convinced by this. How can we tell that a four-velocity is $u_\mu = \{1,0,0,0\}$? Such a four velocity is surely not normalized under the metric we receive later and thus should hold no physical meaning.

Comment: I guess this is maybe a dumb question. The only answer that I can think of is that we think of the spacetime as having a underlying metric $\eta$ on which we solve the linearized Einstein equations for the metric pertubation $h$ and we finally get our overall metric $g$, but this just seems really funky to me.

Answer (score 0):

You are considering only weak fields, thus any corrections to $T_{00}=\rho$ due to normalization will be even weaker and will not be kept in the metric within linear approximation.

You can see this directly by adding normalization $u_\mu=(A,0,0,0)$, which will lead to the metric

$$
ds^2 = -(1+ 2 A^2\Phi) dt^2 + (1- 2 A^2\Phi) (dx^2 + dy^2 + dz^2),
$$

From which you will get
$$A^2=\frac{1}{4\Phi}\left[\sqrt{1+8\Phi}-1\right]=1-\Phi+o(\Phi^2)$$